# Finding the time period under variable acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, rotational-dynamics

"A moves in a circle of radius $R$ such the it's tangential and centripetal accelerations are always equal in magnitude. It's inital velocity is $v_0$. Find the time period of the first revolution."

From $\int_{0}^{t} \omega(t)dt = 2\pi$ I know that knowing $\omega(t)$ will allow us to solve for $t$ but how do we we find it? All we're given is it's initial velocity and that it is always equal to the tangential acceleration, not how it changes-what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that the tangential acceleration $Rd\omega/dt=\omega ^2 R$. So now you can integrate twice and find $\theta(t)$.